# sqoop syntax to import to kudu table

Tags: sqoop, apache-kudu

We'd like to test Kudu and need to import data. Sqoop seems like the correct choice. I find references that you can import to Kudu but no specifics. Is there any way to import to Kudu using Sqoop?

Answer (score 3):

Not at this time.  See:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2903 - Add Kudu connector for Sqoop

Comment: As a workaround, you can import to HDFS and then use Impala to write data to Kudu.